# WOPI Validator Application Not Working. It returns 404 Not Found

Tags: ms-wopi

I am trying to integrate with WOPI online through the Office Cloud Storage Program Partner Program

To do that integration, you have to use the validation application URL by using .wopitest file. It was working fine before but today it gives me 404 Not Found

My Testing URL: https://ffc-onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/WopiTestFrame.aspx?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&dchat=1&hid=951a6eb2-6cd8-4c6d-9258-95f2d420b241&sc=746e9e3b-8a2e-4bc1-810c-01ce605911d1&wopisrc=https://<-myRestAPIURL->/wopi/files/1051&IsLicensedUser=edit&testcategory=All

Is there anyone having the same issue or it is an implementation issue?

Note: for word documents, it is working but I need to run the full test for other issues

Answer (score 1):

It still not working but you can run the validation locally. Here are the steps on windows:

1. Make sure you have at least.net core 2.2.1
2. Download the validator project from github https://github.com/Microsoft/wopi-validator-core
3. Rebuild the project and open the command line
4. Navigate to the bin folder netcoreapp2.0 folder
5. Run the command dotnet run --project
   ./src/WopiValidator/WopiValidator.csproj --framework netcoreapp2.0
   -- -t MyAccessToken -l 0 -w http://localhost:5000/wopi/files/1 -e OfficeOnline -s

Note:

- Provide a valid access token and your WOPI REST end point URL
- Maybe you will need to disable the Proofkeys validation on your end point to make it run

All steps mentioned on the project home page at github

Comment: I have similar issue, i was reading your post, it shows that you can test the WOPI on your localhost? it will solve many of our problems and their documentation website is really bad!
what did you do in order to be able to run and test it on your localhost fallback url?
installing this dotnet project and run it on local is the key?